# How do I keep a (non-persistent) event page loaded while navigating between the pages of one domain?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Google Chrome extension that will load the content script for all the pages on one website (i.e. the manifest specifies http://website.com/*).  The extension also loads a very large amount of data from local storage (which is surprisingly slow!).  So, to reduce load-time, I only want to load from storage once and keep the data in memory for the entire session.

The wrong way to do this is to use a background page (or event page with persistent:true).  This would work because the background page could load the data from storage only once and hold it in memory.  Then each time the content script reloaded (e.g. when the user navigates to a new page), it could request the data from the background page.  The problem with this option is that it needlessly uses a large chunk of memory even though the user may only visit website.com infrequently.  Basically, this is the problem with background pages in general, but in this case it's especially bad because the data from local storage is so large, and therefore the memory used is very large.

What I'd like to do instead is to use a non-persistent event page.  As above, when the user navigates to website.com, the event page will load the data from local storage and the content script will retrieve the data from the event page.  All I need to do is prevent the event page from unloading until the user navigates away from the domain.  The event page could listen for navigation of the active tab and allow itself to unload when the domain changed away from website.com.

From [Chrome developer documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages):

> the event page will not unload until all visible views (for example, popup windows) are closed and all message ports are closed.

Message ports close when the page is navigated, so that's not an option.  Could I somehow create a view that stays visible during navigation of the active tab? Or is there some other solution?

Comment: A port will close, but I don't think that means event page will immediately unload. Chrome gives it a couple of seconds before considering it idle. So if you re-establish the port connection after navigation fast enough (at `document_start`?), it should do the trick.

Comment: Posted as a comment, since I'm not sure it will work. Can you try?

Comment: Can't you just use `chrome.storage.local` from the content script instead of getting the data from the background page?

Comment: To add to RobW's comment - you still need to pass the message to the content script, so it won't be much more work for Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, Xan.  I will try your suggestion and report results.  Rob, the reason I'm loading chrome.local.storage into the background page instead of the content script is because it takes about 1.5 seconds to load the 3MB file from storage.  The page is frozen while the extension JS executes, and that added delay is annoying.

Comment: @Xan - you're correct:  The event page takes several seconds to unload, and as long as we're on the same website, the content script reloads, thus reopening the message port, thus preventing the event page from unloading.  This means makes the script much than I expected because there's no need for the event page to monitor the navigation/status of the tab that's running the content script.  

What's odd is, unless my listening code is wrong, runtime.Port.onDisconnect never gets called event when the content script is unloaded due to its tab being navigated or closed.

Comment: Maybe because it's not `runtime.Port.onDisconnect`, it's `portObject.onDisconnect`. Unlike most events, those are per-instance.